# Real-time data sharing in Svelte between unrelated components

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a case where I have two tabs open
`localhost:5000/` and `localhost:5000/stream` and would like to update a variable in `/` path and see that change in `stream` path in real time. Store doesn't work like that, and if I use local storage with store, I get the data on `stream` page only after refreshing it, which is not what I need. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**use localStorage**

As you are already doing, but you also have to listen to changes in the storage:

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
  const stored = window.localStorage.getItem(...)
  // update the store
})
```

This works fine if you want the data to persist even if the user browses away.

**BroadcastChannel API**

An alternative approach is to use the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) where you can create a construction that is only persistent as long as at least 1 tab is open.

The concept would be the same here: listen to changes in the channel and update the store, if you update the store itself, broacast it.

Comment: BroadcastChannel is absolutely the way to go.